# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

$$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n}\right)$$

Intuitively, it seems that you are adding infinite of $\frac{1}{n}$ and then taking the limit as n goes to infinity, which would seem to give zero.

Further, manipulating it as follows:

$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \lim_{n\to \infty } \, \frac{1}{n}$$

gives that you are adding up an infinite number of zeroes, which would support the idea that the limit is zero.

Is this right?

Comment: no, this question seems to be not well defined to have an answer in this form

Comment: Please check the source of the question as it is wrong as written currently. Probably it should be $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\sum_{k = 1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}\right)$$

Comment: @user2612743 : Did you mean $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty$ or $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n$ ${}\  {}$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: If the current form is correct, you should realize that this is an example where you cannot exchange the limit and the infinite sum.  If you exchange the limit and sum you get $0$, but the correct answer is $\infty$.

Comment: No, the current form is correct. You are adding up infinite 1/n then taking the limit as n goes to infinity. So is the answer undefined as you are left with $\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{\infty}{n}$? How come when switching the limit inside you get 0?

Comment: @Stephen: That's the largest possible error I have ever seen.

Comment: You are adding infinitely many infinitesimally small numbers. I suppose this problem was given to illustrate the fallacy of $\infty \times 0$. Not sure what the genesis of this problem is

Comment: Remember that for monotone convergence, you need to be monotonically INCREASING. And for dominated convergence, there have to be an INTEGRABLE dominating function. Neither apply here, illustrating the fact that the hypothesis of either theorem are important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is not defined, under the usual definitions of real analysis, or any definition of limits I know. (However, there may exist other definitions of limits that I'm unaware of, in settings larger than calculus or real analysis, and I'd guess that under definitions, the limit, if defined at all, would be $\infty$, whatever that means.)

In real analysis, we have definitions for $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$, where $a_n$ is a sequence of **real numbers**. Sometimes we use the symbol $\infty$ to denote that a sequence of real numbers grows arbitrarily large, and that therefore (in particular) the sequence has no limit in the real numbers.

However, what we have here is **not** the limit of a sequence of real numbers:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$$ where $a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1n$. Here, the expression $a_n$, itself an infinite sum (and therefore being a limit of finite sums, under the usual definitions of infinite sums) happens in this case to not be a real number:
$$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1n = \lim_{m\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac1n = \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{m}n = \infty$$ (here I have used "$= \infty$" in the last step as notation to say that it is unbounded: does not exist in the real numbers).

So you are trying to find $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$, where $a_n$ is a limit that **does not exist**. If you want to allow "$\infty$" as an expression for manipulation, you could write $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \infty,$$ which is still not covered by the usual definitions.

But if you extend the definitions in any reasonable way to cover cases like this, I guess you'd define $\lim_{n \to \infty} \infty = \infty$. Note however that this is *not* standard.

Comment: There is actually no problem in dealing with limits in the topological space $[-\infty,+\infty]$.

Comment: A calculus example of such a use of $\infty$ is the pretty common (and easy to memorize) definition of $\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n$ as $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup_{k\geq n}x_k$.

Answer (score 3):

$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\infty=\infty$ since $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n}=\infty\,.$

Answer (score 1):

My hint:

I use Riemann sum integration:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{k}=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}dx=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\ln 1-\ln x\right)=\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

What is one to understand from $\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{n}\right)$?

is it $\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=1}^{n } \frac{1}{n}\right)$ or $\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=1}^{n^2 } \frac{1}{n}\right)$ or $\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=1}^{\ln n } \frac{1}{n}\right)$?

Following part is added to show the difference between two of the above:

$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=1}^{n } \frac{1}{n}\right)$=1

$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\sum _{k=1}^{n^2 } \frac{1}{n}\right)=\infty$

Comment: That you are adding up an infinite amount of 1/n

Comment: @user2612743: infinite? at what rate? linear, quadratic or logarithmic rate? This answer was meant to show that the rate that they are being added makes a difference, add too many terms faster then it could diverge, add too few then it will converge.

Comment: I don't see why this is relevant. $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty}$ is defined as usual.

Comment: @JLA : I added extra info at the bottom, in this case there is a limiting factor involved within each summand, that is what makes the usual defined version ambiguous in this case.

Comment: @Arjang But it's not ambiguous, what you wrote isn't what the poster wrote. What they wrote means $\lim_{n\to \infty } \lim_{m\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{n}$.